# Is there the ability for SQL to take a value, use logic, and result a different value

Tags: sql, case

This may be a silly question, but I'm trying to essentially take a value that's in a field and IF contains "Tele" THEN result Televideo. Or it might be better: IF other than "Office" THEN result "Televideo". <--This might be easier. I know it has to be apart of my select statement, I just didn't know if I could call it out and then get the result to be different than the actual value there.

Other than select location_value from appt_data where appointment_date = '2020-12-04'...can I accomplish the above? I feel like I'd need a CASE statement and probably a =! operator. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when location_value like 'Tele%' then 'televideo'
             else 'Office'
        end) as location_grouping
from t;
```

Or perhaps:

```
select t.*,
       (case when location_value = 'Office' then 'Office'
             else 'televideo'
        end) as location_grouping
from t;
```

Comment: So, here's the larger statement...I'm trying to understand where to place this cause of the "," you have seems to separate from the larger statement.

select
 view_episode_summary_current.patient_name_first,
 substring(view_episode_summary_current.patient_home_phone, 1, 3) || ' ' || substring(view_episode_summary_current.patient_home_phone, 5, 8) as "Phone",
 convert (varchar(10), CAST(appointment_date as date), 101) as "Date",
 CONVERT (time,appointment_start_time) as "Appt Time",
 Left(staff_name,charindex(',', staff_name)-1) as "Staff Last Name",
 location_value as "Location"

Comment: Guess I'm not understanding where the t.* and location_grouping are for? In interpretation, is this what you were thinking? ...,
 Left(staff_name,charindex(',', staff_name)-1) as "Staff Last Name",
 select location_value,
 (case when location_value = 'Office' then 'Office'
             else 'televideo'
        end) as location_grouping

Comment: The `t` is just for your table or CTE or subquery or whatever.  The `location_grouping` is the result of the `case` expression.

Comment: Thank you so much! I took what you presented and got it to display without any issues. Much appreciated!